# Modify Date with custom values in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, select, timestamp

I have 2 datetimes in MYSQL table. I need to get a new datetime using part of the dates.

Example: Date 1: `2012-10-23 10:44:21` , Date 2: `2011-06-02 05:40:10`

I need Date 3: `2012-10-02 05:40:10` Like this.

Year and Month from Date 1 and the rest from Date 2. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT('2012-10-23 10:44:21', '%Y-%m-'), DATE_FORMAT('2011-06-02 05:40:10', '%d %H:%i:%s')) test;
```

Output is:

```
test
------------------
2012-10-02 05:40:10
```

Answer (score 0):

Build a string using the values you need:

```
Select concat(Year(date 1),
Month(date 1),
+ right(date 2, 11) ) as stringDate
;
```

Then use `makedate`, `str_to_date`,`date_format` functions.

```
Select str_to_date(stringDate, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s');
```

PS: on mobile unable to type entire working code.

Answer (score 0):

to get year do this

```
    YEAR(date1)
```

and the month

```
     MONTH(date1)
```

to get the rest from date2

```
   SUBSTRING('date2', 8 , 11)
```